# how to fix "Blocked due to unauthorized access (403)" in magento

Tags: http-status-403

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix "Blocked due to unauthorized access (403)"

Answer (score 0):

The website you are referring to [www.bottegadelletisane.it](http://www.bottegadelletisane.it) is throwing 403. I think you need to resolve that before the google's crawler can visit the website again.

[image]